# Is GCC or Clang correct about the name of a function parameter being in scope in its own default argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

I have a little toy program:

```
static int value = 0;

int function(int &value=value) {
    return value;
}

int main() {
    function();
}
```

Compiling with g++ 7.2:

> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra test.cc -o test

No problem.

Compiling with clang++-3.9:

> clang++-3.9 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra test.cc -o test

```
test.cc:3:25: error: default argument references parameter 'value'
int function(int &value=value) {
                        ^~~~~
test.cc:8:5: error: no matching function for call to 'function'
    function();
    ^~~~~~~~
test.cc:3:5: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'value', but no arguments were provided
int function(int &value=value) {
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Kaboom.  Who's right?

Comment: `int function(int &value=value)` looks really weird to me.  I'd change that to `int function(int &value = ::value)` so it refers to the global `value` instead of the reference being bound to itself.

Comment: @Eljay `gcc` binds it to the global `value` with `int& value = value`, but I think it's wrong according to the current standard.

Comment: just curious - when you run the gcc one, what's the value of the local value?  (ohh god, that question has all gone wrong)...

Comment: Judging by the fact that you can use `decltype(param)` in the default argument, I'd say the parameter name is in scope and GCC is wrong, but that's not a very strong basis.

Comment: @UKMonkey [Apparently](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfaa2cc9ca1a2594) it is the actual value of `::value`, i.e. the reference does not bind to itself.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think clang is correct. From [basic.scope.pdecl](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.scope.pdecl#1):

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause [[dcl.decl]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.decl)) and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int x = 12;{ int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.  — end example ]

Also, from [dcl.fct.default](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.default#9):

> Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not evaluated. Parameters of a function declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide namespace and class member names

Comment: That looks like the answer, surprised gcc missed that one.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister, yes, it is surprising that g++ would miss this one.

Comment: But this quote does not prohibit default argument from referencing function parameter as clang complains.

Comment: @VTT [This one](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.default#9) does.

Comment: The only use case would be to take the address of the parametrr to define its own value. Who ever did it? Why exposing coder to mistakes for such a unusefull case? The standard is wrong, so gcc is right to be wrong.

Comment: @Oliv, care to elaborate that with a live, or semi-live, example?

Comment: `void foo(ptrdiff_t x = reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>( &x))` taking the address of x before its lifetime has begun is ok, accessing its value is UB in its definition... this is the only use case I see where naming the variable being defined could be not UB. This is essentialy useless. Not talking obviously of unevaluated opperand as decltype... while we already have the type!

Answer (score 18):

Since the OP tagged the question as c++11 I checked that version of the standard and in [[basic.lookup.unqual]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lookup.unqual#11) sub-clause 11 it states explicitly that:

> During the lookup for a name used as a default argument (8.3.6) in a
>   function parameter-declaration-clause or used in the expression of a
>   mem-initializer for a constructor (12.6.2), the function parameter
>   names are visible and hide the names of entities declared in the
>   block, class or namespace scopes containing the function declaration.

Thus, clang is correct.

Answer (score 8):

Clang is correct here.  First a [function's parameter scope](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.param)  is defined as:

> A function parameter (including one appearing in a lambda-declarator) or function-local predefined variable ([dcl.fct.def]) has function parameter scope. The potential scope of a parameter or function-local predefined variable begins at its point of declaration.[...]

and the [point of declaration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.pdecl#1) is defined as

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below. [ Example:
>
> ```
> unsigned char x = 12;
> { unsigned char x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. — end example ]

So `value` should be the `value` you just declared and not the one from the global space