# Clang and GCC has an inconsistent interpretation to the case where the parameter name appears as an unevaluated operand

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void fun(int a = sizeof(a)){
    std::cout<< a<<std::endl;
}
int main(){
   fun();
}
```

Consider this [case](https://godbolt.org/z/vn6K1c8Eq). Clang accepts it while GCC rejects it. According to [dcl.fct.default] p9

> A default argument is evaluated each time the function is called with no argument for the corresponding parameter. A parameter **shall not** appear as a **potentially-evaluated expression** in a default argument.

[basic.def.odr] p2

> An expression or conversion is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand

`sizeof` is not a potentially-evaluated expression and `a` can be found at this point. I wonder which one is correct for this case?

Comment: Dup of [Using a parameter's name inside its own default value - is it legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513156/using-a-parameters-name-inside-its-own-default-value-is-it-legal) and [Function default argument value depending on argument name in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461415/function-default-argument-value-depending-on-argument-name-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is wrong. It assumes that `a` is not yet in scope in the default argument, although generally the point of declaration is immediately after the declarator before the initializer and none of the exceptions apply here. [[basic.scope.pdecl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope.pdecl#1)

An older bug report for this is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50479).

Note however, that the bug report has equivalent code to yours, but claims it should be ill-formed. That is because it was written before [CWG 2082](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2082) which allowed the use of a parameter in an unevaluated context in the default argument.

Related question regarding this GCC bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771614/is-gcc-or-clang-correct-about-this-behavior/48771883).